# Conflict between jQuery 1.4.2 and 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a background slideshow that uses the jQuery 1.9.1 which is called here "jacksis.js" in body section and i have another submenu slider that uses jQuery 1.4.2 as in here is called "core.js" in head section. However, when i added the jQuery 1.9.1, the slider on 1.4.2 stopped working. I tried the noConflict() mode without success and the jQuery call innstead of the "$". Down below, the "ss1_wrapper" is using the 1.4.2 and the "cbp_bislideshow" the 1.9.1. What could be wrong in my

```
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,9,10,11">

    <link href="index_files/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="index_files/core.js"></script>

    <script src="index_files/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body id="page">    

    <ul id="cbp-bislideshow" class="cbp-bislideshow">
        ...    
    </ul>

    <form class="" name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="index.htm" id="aspnetForm">

    <div class="ss1_wrapper">    
     ......
    </div>

    <script>$(function() {
       $('#slideshow_1').cycle({
            fx: 'scrollHorz',       
            easing: 'easeInOutCirc',
            speed:  1100, 
            timeout: 6000, 
            pager: '.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_paging', 
            prev: '.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_prev',
            next: '.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_next',
            // using the "before" function, we grab the content of the active slide and show it in our custom box overlay
            before: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement) {
                var data = $('.data', $(nextSlideElement)).html();
                $('.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_box .data').fadeOut(300, function(){
                    $('.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_box .data').remove();
                    $('<div class="data">'+data+'</div>').hide().appendTo('.ss1_wrapper .slideshow_box').fadeIn(600);
                });
            }
        });

        // not using the 'pause' option. instead make the slideshow pause when the mouse is over the whole wrapper
        $('.ss1_wrapper').mouseenter(function(){
            $('#slideshow_1').cycle('pause');
        }).mouseleave(function(){
            $('#slideshow_1').cycle('resume');
        });

    });</script>

    </form>

    <script src="index_files/jacksis.js"></script>

    <script src="index_files/js/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"></script>

    <script src="index_files/js/cbpBGSlideshow.min.js"></script>

    <script>$(function() {
            cbpBGSlideshow.init();});
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="index_files/quant.js"></script>

    </body>
```

I am receiving only one error in firebug in line core.js (1.4.2) line 1993:

```
TypeError: jQuery.browser is undefined
```

and the error is in that function at line 4 (it's line 1993 in the original file)

```
(function($) { 
    $(document).ready( function() {
        // Fix background image caching problem
        if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
            try { 
                document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true); 
            } catch(err) {}
        }
```

What couldn't be wrong in my code if i tried all the possibilities of getting away with jQuery conflict?

UPDATE:

I introduced jQuery 1.7.1 and deleted both 1.4.2 and 1.9.1, then now i have both my Slider and Background slideshow working again together BUT my drop-down menu (which could be seen on my webpage www.es-processing.com) is not working anymore. On the online version it is working, but right now, on the version i'm working on it's not functioning at all. You can have an idea from my dropdown on my webpage to see which jQuery functions it follows and how to adapt them on the new 1.7.1 i put.

Comment: Do you really need both versions of jQuery? What happens if you just use one?

Comment: .browser became deprecated in later versions of jQuery, you'd need to use the jQuery.migrate plugin as a workaround until you use normal feature detection instead

Comment: @mason i tried staying on either one of them but it's either the slideshow or the slider working. Not both.

Comment: Using two versions of jQuery on the same page, especially two so widely separated, is a recipe for much pain and frustration. An old library that requires an outdated jQuery is probably abandoned by its author and things will only get worse.

Comment: I agree with @Pointy on this. Try and use a library that will work with an updated version of jquery. If there is a rush you can use https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/ for now and it should solve the .browser error you have.

Comment: Did you wrap the code in jQuery(document).ready(function($){  }); . Is that what you meant by using the jQuery instead of $ ?

Comment: That snippet from core.js doesn't look right to me. Did they really mean to use the `jQuery` variable instead of the `$` argument? Just a thought.